# Load the dataset in Pytorch

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, dataset

I cannot upload my dataset into Pytorch.

I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from skimage import io
import torchvision.transforms as transforms


class CatsAndDogsDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.annotations = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations) #24 images
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotatoins.iloc[index, 0])
        image = io.imread(img_path)
        y_label = torch.tensor(int(self.annotations.iloc[index, 1]))
        
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        
        return (image, y_label)

dataset = CatsAndDogsDataset(csv_file = 'C:/***/Dataset/PetImages/Shuffled', root_dir = 'C:/***/Dataset/PetImages/Shuffled', 
                     transform = transforms.ToTensor())
```

and I keep receiving the error in form of: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/***/Dataset/PetImages/Shuffled'`

Here I have two questions:

1. When I have been trying to upload a similar dataset without defining the class and simply using `cv2.imread` function, there was no problems with permission. So why does this error pops up?
2. How can I upload the dataset using this method?

Thank you in advance!

Regards

Comment: `C:/***/Dataset/PetImages/Shuffled` looks like a folder, not a file, and particularly not a .csv file. Should'nt your first argument to the dataset be a path to a csv file ?

Comment: It looks like `image = io.imread(img_path)` raises the error. I would suggest converting the path object to string and verify that it does not start from 'file://' or 'file:\\'.

Comment: And also, shouldn't `imread` get a path to a single file?

Comment: Thank you for reply! Yes, you are right. But when I change to```dataset = CatsAndDogsDataset(csv_file = 'CatsNDogs.xlsx', root_dir = 'C:/***/Dataset/PetImages/Shuffled', 
                     transform = transforms.ToTensor())``` I get an error ``` FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CatsNDogs.xlsx' ```
I am confused with the roles of ```root_dir``` and ```csv_file```,because when I read the documentation of ```pandas.read_csv``` the first parameter there is ```filepath_or_buffer```, that is why I have used the path there.But ```root_dir``` plays the same role, isn't it?

Comment: @KateMelnykova Hi, thank you for the reply!

When I convert path to string, I get the following result: ```C:\***\Dataset\PetImages\CatsNDogs.csv ```

Comment: @KateMelnykova
Moreover, about ```io.imread(img_path)``` - I am not sure, but probably you are right. So I have changed the folder of my .csv file to keep the pictures in the folder (Shuffled) alone. However, I keep receiving the error ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CatsNDogs.csv'```
Where can I specify the directory? When I give an absolute path in ```csv_file``` I get ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte``` Do you know how can I solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: In some comments, you mention a `CatsNDogs.xlsx` and sometimes a `CatsNDogs.csv`. Which filetype is it actually ? Csv or xlsx ? You are not asking pandas to read a xlsx as a csv, are you ?